# How to jail linux user

Tags: linux, chroot, jail

Is there something similar to chroot, but for users?

We are about to grant access to our servers for a client and would like them to see only the directories we allow.

Comment: Isn't that what permissions were designed for?

Comment: I want to go a bit further than just denying read / write access.

Comment: chroot only denies read/write access.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Google search on "openssh jail" led me to [SSHjail for openSSH](http://antitese.org/sshjail/). If your client uses ssh/scp to access the said servers, this might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

The "best answer" from 2009 is outdated.
OpenSSH now comes with the `ChrootDirectory` option.
See http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/590 which is for an already-old version of ssh.

Answer (score 4):

It is important to note that chroot(2) is not meant for security purposes.  It is incredibly easy to escape a chroot jail.  See this article on [abusing chroot](http://kerneltrap.org/Linux/Abusing_chroot) for more information.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Comment non-answer, link-only and link already dead (server down).

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to go to that extreme, [SE Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selinux) (or any other [mandatory access control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control)) is a definite improvement of the default unix permissions.

Answer (score 1):

An effective way to do this is to use [lshell](https://github.com/ghantoos/lshell)

Answer (score 0):

No easy way to jail users in their homedirs.
BTW, I would NEVER give access to my systems to someone I don't trust a minimum.

Last time I did, I used an "unescapable" menu based on
http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/A_menu_box
The .bashrc launches this script you would not escape :

```
~/.bashrc :
(LAST LINE)
./menu.sh; exit 0
```

Yes, I had to write scripts for each and every menu item (get logs, check sys, ...) but nobody to run 'chown -R root:root /' instead of *.
Priceless.

[EDIT] : create a dedicated user, don't do this as root !!!

Comment: As mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/21649384/2404541 a "user could simply script sending a bunch of ^Z or ^C characters to the client right after entering the password to completely abridge any efforts made in the bashrc". `lshell` seems like the best solution from my reading so far...