# How to enable access to the atd service for one user and deny for another in CentOS 8?

Tags: linux, redhat, gnome-terminal, centos8, rhel8

Is it possible to restrict access to the service for specific user and allow for another?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21649384/13126651 may this help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can explicitly control who can create `at` jobs. See at.allow(5) and at.deny(5) man pages.

> The /etc/at.allow and /etc/at.deny files determine which user can submit commands for later execution via at(1) or batch(1).
>
> The format of the files is a list of usernames, one on each line. Whitespace is not permitted.
>
> If the file /etc/at.allow exists, only usernames mentioned in it are allowed to use at.
>
> If /etc/at.allow does not exist, /etc/at.deny is checked.  every username not mentioned in it is then allowed to use at.
>
> An empty /etc/at.deny means that every user may use at.
>
> If neither exists, only the superuser is allowed to use at.