# Access Control on Adhoc Commands in RunDeck

Tags: acl, access-control, rundeck

Is there any way that I restrict a user to run a specific command? For example: I want only Admin users should be allowed to run "rm" commands on a node. Or I need to restrict the commands that requires write access on to the filesystem of the node.

Answer (score 0):

Rundeck doesn't work in that way. If you're using a specific user to dispatch commands on a node, Rundeck uses that user permissions to launch their commands. In your case, the best approach is to use a restricted user account on your remote node to limit commands.

Please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21649384/10426011).