# Restrict user access to JUST ONE specific file and nothing else

Tags: linux, permissions, acl

I have a situation where I want a user to be able to have **rwx access to just one specific file, the command `nano`, `/bin/bash` and NOTHING ELSE**. The user will be able to log in with ssh.

I followed the second answer from Victor Wong from this question: [How to limit user commands in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498667/how-to-limit-user-commands-in-linux) to set up the thing with nano, but so far I couldn't manage to restrict the access to just this file.

With normal linux permissions, the user will always be able to navigate to /etc and even read /etc/groups and more.

I tried these two commands:

`setfacl -m u:myuser:0 /` and then `setfacl -m u:myuser:rwx /etc/network/interfaces`

But then linux  tells me permission denied on `/etc/network/interfaces`, I guess because the restriction on / is prioritized or just comes first.

I did not try root jail since I read, that you can still open other files with nano then. Am I right with that?

I googled for a couple of hours now and played around but couldn't find a solution yet. Can you guys help me or at least give me the buzzwords too google for / try out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a chroot jail following the steps in this article:

https://www.tecmint.com/restrict-ssh-user-to-directory-using-chrooted-jail/

with creating a hard link to the file I needed the user to be able to edit. I also added `nano` to the available commands.

It works like a charm.

I also skipped the substep 14 to add `ForceCommand internal-sftp` to the `sshd_config` file, since I still need ssh.

In case someone runs accross this post and wants to add `nano`:

**You need to add `/lib/terminfo` with all its content to your `/home/myuser/lib/` folder!**

Answer (score 0):

Which user tried to run

```
setfacl -m u:myuser:0 / 
setfacl -m u:myuser:rwx /etc/network/interfaces
```

commands?
Does the /etc/network/interfaces belongs to that user?
Can you share current `getfacl` command output?
Please try to be more specific with users and operations.

By the way for files can you try using `-M` option with setfacl and do it with a privileged user like the owner of `/etc/network/nterfaces`.

```
setfacl - u:myuser:rwx /etc/network/interfaces
```

You can try this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. After trying around some more I ended up using a chroot jail. That works as intended

Answer (score 0):

I would write a [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) C program using relevant [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), compile it carefully (into a static executable), have that C code being reviewed by colleagues, and make that executable the login shell (see [chmod(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chmod.1.html), [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [seteuid(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/seteuid.2.html), [credentials(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html), [shells(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/shells.5.html), [elf(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html) and [passwd(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/passwd.5.html) and [pam_shells(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pam_shells.8.html)...) of that particular user.

**Be careful when coding *setuid* executables** (a bug would open a huge security hole). Read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/)

BTW, once your user is running `/bin/bash`, he is capable of doing everything. Maybe you want to permit only a [restricted bash shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Restricted-Shell.html)?