# Disable File and Folder Delete Privilege for Particular User

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel7

How can I disable the below commands for a particular Linux user (non superuser/not in sudoers file) in RHEL?

- rm
- rmdel
- unlink
- mv

Comment: You can take away write access to particular directories, but it's a fool's errand to try to prevent access to basic commands.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I didn't understand, do you are have access to sudo?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21649384/13126651 duplicate of this?

Comment: No sudo access.